# Git is not working properly when installing with chef

Tags: git, chef-solo, amazon-linux

I'm provisioning my servers with Chef. For git I'm using the community cookbook and is installing version 1.8.3.1 in Amazon Linux. However after it gets installed I don't get any output while running git commands as git ls-remote or git clone (also it won't clone projects). I Googled with no luck.

Comment: Is there any specific error when doing a `git clone`?

Comment: No output whatsoever, 

`git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv`

`Cloning into 'rbenv'...`

but the repo is not cloned, also git ls-remote doesn't returns anything. @mtak

Comment: Can you run `dpkg-query -S \`which git\`` to determine if the git binary came from the git package?

Comment: This is not a debian based linux distro. Amazon Linux is RHEL based so dpkg-query is not available.

Comment: I do get this in dmesg: `[1278397.007329] traps: git-remote-http[1296] trap invalid opcode ip:7ffe0de9b460 sp:7fffeabfe758 error:0 in libfreebl3.so[7ffe0de4a000+70000]`

Answer (score 0):

**2014-04-16** @LuisDUrraca provided more information:

The `invalid opcode` in dmesg is a product of AWS' Xen hypervisor. It can mean that the action is not supported by the hypervisor in I/O requests or that you are running out of memory. Check your RAM and [Steal Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703320/aws-ec2-high-cpu-alarms-going-off).

---

I recently heard someone complaining of the same with puppet. I'd wager that the problem is more likely with other operating system components, not with Chef itself.

1. Did you try running `git clone` with `--verbose`? You should also check to see that you are able to connect to the remote host otherwise (`ping`, `curl`, `ssh`)?
2. Did you verify that git was or was not installed before? A very old git installation shouldn't, but could distrub the community cookbook code logic. Have you checked the output of `git --version` to see that you've [1.8.3.1](http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2013.09-packages/#g) now.   You can also verify the [Chef Entreprise logs](http://docs.opscode.com/server_logs.html) or package manager logs for the installation.
3. Are all of this group of servers affected? Did you try reproducing the problem in a virtual machine or development environment? In a VM, you could try manually removing and reinstalling git to see if that resolves the problem. If it does, and it likely should, then you could just replicate a cookbook to do that across your servers.
4. If you determine that `yum` is the point of failure, `yum clean && yum check-update` may be a starting point (i.e. via cluster SSH).

Comment: 3.   yeah, all my others amazon linux are affected. I tried reinstalling manually different versions of git, same issue.

2.   I don't know if git was installed before I don't think it was. git --version returns 1.8.3.1.

1. git clone --verbose doesn't returns any additional output however in the dmesg I found: `[1278397.007329] traps: git-remote-http[1296] trap invalid opcode ip:7ffe0de9b460 sp:7fffeabfe758 error:0 in libfreebl3.so[7ffe0de4a000+70000]`

Comment: yum can cause issues like this?

Comment: Supposing an installation was corrupted, yes. Low RAM or [high Steal Time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703320/aws-ec2-high-cpu-alarms-going-off) are likely culprits though, if you're running a t1.mirco instance for example.